# getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); - Kotlin? - Remove Shadow from ActionBar

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-actionbar

I want to remove the shadow below my action bar. The java code for that is
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
the kotlin code should be 
supportActionBar?.setElevation(0)
That's what I tried but AndroidStudio is giving me the following error: 
the integer literal does not conform to the expected type float

I hope somebody can help me to fix that problem.

Regards, Jeremy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do `supportActionBar?.setElevation(0f)` and because it's Kotlin, you can drop the `set`

```
supportActionBar?.elevation = 0f
```

Comment: It is working but is there any way to remove it at design time itself instead of runtime